Kendo UI for jQuery row selection issue after updating from v2014.3.1314 to v2024.1.319
I am currently updating Kendo UI for jQuery in my project from version v2014.3.1314 to v2024.1.319. After the update, I encountered an issue with row selection in my grid.
var row = $(this).closest("tr"),
    dataItem = grid.dataItem(row),
    isSelected = row.attr('aria-selected'),
    isClass = row.hasClass('k-state-selected');

Before the update, isSelected was true and isClass was true. However, after updating Kendo UI, isSelected becomes undefined and isClass becomes false. This change is causing issues in my application as I rely on these variables in further code execution.
I have checked that the data in row and dataItem remains the same after the update. The problem seems to be specifically related to the variables isSelected and isClass.
Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

You need to include more details, at what point are you running this? from what I can see, aria-selected is still on the table row which would indicate you're running it before it's selected or after it's been deselected, as for the isClass, it would appear that k-state-selected has been substituted with k-selected.

I am running this after selecting the row.

and how are you implementing this? it would appear that the state of that table row isn't being updated when your code runs.

yes currently it is not updating but before updating KendoUI library it was working fine

After conducting a search, I came across an answer on Telerik that states the 'k-state-selected' attribute has been changed to 'k-selected' in the new version. After making this change, my issue was resolved.
https://www.telerik.com/forums/was-the-grid-k-state-selected-css-class-name-removed-for-selected-rows#5566372
